# ODBC ERROR WITHE SQLINTEGER

Tags: c++, sql, jdbc, odbc

What does this error mean I have tried All possible means of changing it but it is not working.

cannot convert ‘SQLINTEGER*’ to ‘long int*’ for argument ‘6’ to ‘SQLRETURN SQLGetData(void*, SQLUSMALLINT, SQLSMALLINT, void*, long int, long int*)’emphasized text

```
Here is the code
#ifndef CPSC_408_DB_H
#define CPSC_408_DB_H

#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string> using namespace std;


class Monster {   public:

  Monster(string dsn);   ~Monster();
     void execQuery();


  private:   //used for connection and status   
   SQLHENV env;  
   SQLHDBC dbc;   
   SQLHSTMT stmt;   
   SQLRETURN ret; /* ODBC API return status */   
   SQLCHAR outstr[1024];   SQLSMALLINT outstrlen;




};



#endif


//sql getdata method
/* retrieve column data as a string */
  ret = SQLGetData(stmt, i+1, SQL_C_CHAR,
                         buf, sizeof(buf), &indicator);
```

Comment: That's an error  message. What does your code look like? Perhaps you really are calling the long int* parameter with a SQLINTERGER* - even if it is inadvertant due to mis-casting.?

Comment: @user475529 - thank you for posting the code for the call to SQLGetData. Could you please add the declarations for the variables mentioned in this call that are not already mentioned in your code fragment (that is, the variables i, buf, and indicator)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you'd post the actual call to SQLGetData that the compiler is griping about, along with all related declarations, but I'll take a stab at it.

The last parameter to SQLGetData is supposed to a pointer to a long int (sometimes referred to as an SDWORD in some versions of the ODBC docs), not a pointer to an SQLINTEGER.  Check the type of the variable whose address you're passing and update it as necessary.

Share and enjoy.